# Jsf2 listener not called with f:ajax

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using jsf2 and richfaces 4.

Here is my home.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
    <title>My Web Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/stylesheet/style.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <h:form>

            <rich:panel>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    Statut
                    <div class="status_refresh" style="float:right;">
                        <h:graphicImage styleClass="loading" value="resources/stylesheet/images/refresh.png">
                            <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" listener="#{statusBean.refresh}" render="station_status station_action"/>
                        </h:graphicImage>
                    </div>
                </f:facet>

                <h:panelGroup id="station_status" style="display:inline-block;" class="#{statusBean.stationTableStatus?'status_ok':'status_not_ok'}">
                    <a4j:outputPanel>
                        <rich:tooltip rendered="#{statusBean.stationTableStatus != true}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{statusBean.stationTableStatusMessage}" />
                        </rich:tooltip>
                        <h:outputText value="Table " />
                        <b><h:outputText style="margin-right:10px;" value="Station" /></b>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup id="station_action" rendered="#{statusBean.stationTableStatus != true}">
                    <a4j:status>
                        <f:facet name="start">
                            <div class="loading_container">
                                <h:graphicImage styleClass="loading" value="resources/stylesheet/images/waiting.gif" alt="Please wait ..." />
                            </div>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="stop">
                            <h:commandButton type="button" value="Créer la table">
                                <a4j:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{statusBean.createStationTable}" render="station_status,station_action"/>
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </f:facet>
                    </a4j:status>                       
                </h:panelGroup>

            </rich:panel>

        </h:form>

    </h:panelGrid>

</h:body>

</html>
```

In by backing bean, I have:

```
public void createStationTable()
{
....
}
```

and

```
public void refresh()
{
    System.out.println("******* start refresh() ************");
}
```

And I don't understand why the listener of my button is called but not the one of my image.

I also tried with

```
public void refresh(ActionEvent actionEvent)
```

and

```
public void refresh(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)
```

but none are working.

I also tried with both f:ajax and a4j:ajax. The same result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried your code and it called the listener defined in `<f:ajax>` tag.

I don't know if you missed it while copying, you are missing `</html>`.

For `<h:panelGrid>` you used wrong attribute. It should be `styleClass` instead of `class`

Comment: On witch environment did you try ?  For me I'm working with glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: I tested in Tomcat 7, not in glassfish. I used JSF 2.2 RI.

Comment: Ok, now it's working.  Sometimes there are strange things with glassfish.  Just do an undeploy followed by a deploy in place of redeploy.